# Merging Two tables with non Equivalent Columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi I have two tables with non equivalent columns and no joining key so How Should I merge them to one table.

```
Table A    
ID     Date     Name
1   2019-07-12    A
2   2019-07-12    B


Table B    
City     Salary   
Delhi      100     
Mumbai     200    


Table 
    ID    DATE       Name    City     Salary   

    1   2019-07-12    A      Delhi      100
    2   2019-07-12    B      Mumbai     200
```

Comment: You mean a basic join? Please take a SQL tutorial first.

Comment: basis join is not working Sir ... giving the nulls...

Comment: How do you know which City belongs to which Name? You need a connection for that